# Jquery Remove/Add Image on Click

Tags: jquery, image, class, addition

At the moment I have a div with the "1st-image" inside. This is the default for each tab. However when I click the href 2 not only do I want the tab to change, but I also want the image to change to the 2nd-image.

Here is a section of the code I am working with:

```
 <img src="images/1st-image.jpg">
<!-- <img src="images/2nd-image.jpg"> -->

        <div id="tabmenu">
          <ul id="Tabnav">
             <li><a href="#/" class="active">1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#/">2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#/">3</a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
```

And here is the JQuery which currently works to navigate the tabs:

```
    $('#tab-content div').hide();
    $('#tab-content div:first').show();

      $('#Tabnav li').click(function() {
      $('#Tabnav li a').removeClass("active");
      $(this).find('a').addClass("active");
      $('#tab-content div').hide();

    var indexer = $(this).index(); 
    $('#tab-content div:eq(' + indexer + ')').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property data-other-src to each href with the path to the image you want to display. So for example the 2nd link becomes

```
<li><a href="/#" data-other-src="images/2nd-image">2</a></li>
```

Add this to the .click function:

```
 $('#tab-content div').find('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-other-src'))
```

I got the jsFiddle working as I think you want it. Change the html to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div class="TabWrap">   
    <div class="brewImg">
     <img id="image1" src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/75088000/jpg/_75088402_022410338-1.jpg">
     <div id="tabmenu">
       <ul id="Tabnav">
        <li><a href="#/" data-other-src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/75088000/jpg/_75088402_022410338-1.jpg" class="active">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/" data-other-src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/75089000/jpg/_75089349_s9tjnwq7.jpg">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/" data-other-src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/75087000/jpg/_75087897_022408402.jpg">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> 

    <div id="tab-content">

        <div id="tab1">

            1

        </div>

        <div id="tab2">

       2

        <div id="tab3">

        3    

        </div>

        </div>
        </div>
```

and the javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#tab-content div').hide();
$('#tab-content div:first').show();

$('#Tabnav li').click(function() {    
    $('#Tabnav li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).find('a').addClass("active");
    $('#tab-content div').hide();
    $('#image1').attr('src', $(this).find('a').attr('data-other-src'))

    var indexer = $(this).index(); 
    $('#tab-content div:eq(' + indexer + ')').fadeIn();
});
});
```

Over on the left panel on the jsFiddle select jQuery 2.1.0 under framework and extensions. The picture at the top which I've named image1 changes when you click on each link.

Comment: Hmm, this didn't seem to do anything?

Comment: Put it on jsFiddle. It works if the references are right but I can't check the actual name of the div containing the image or the path to your images

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sjc9G/

That's the jsFiddle straight from my document. For some reason the script isn't working on there but it does in Dreamweaver.